# Using Raspberry Pi with XBee

Tags: xbee

I'm working in a project to make a communication between the RPi and the XBee module, but I really don't know how to begin. I'm looking for some ebooks to learn but I didn't find yet. Does anyone have some idea about how to begin?

Comment: Look up the book Building Wireless Sensor Networks, Robert Faludi, published by O'Reilly. Best book ever. OK, it deals with the Arduino, and not the Pi, but the knowledge that you gain from the book will thereafter be able to be applied to the Pi.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to hookup the XBee module to the RPi is through an Xbee USB adapter (hardware wise).

I [thought this was a really easy tutorial to follow](https://jeffskinnerbox.wordpress.com/2013/03/20/the-simplest-xbee-network/).  It also goes over setting up an Arduino with Xbee.